# Graded readers for Swedish?

Tags: electronic-resources, physical-resources, graded-readers, swedish

As several other questions have pointed out, graded readers are a good type of material for extensive reading. Where can I find graded readers in Swedish?

Answer (score 1):

http://ll-forlaget.se/hem/nivaer?levelId=538

You can check out this webpage that offers books in easy Swedish sorted into three levels of difficulty.

Let me quote the website about the different levels:

> **Nivå 1**
>
> I nivå 1 dominerar ofta bilderna och det är lite eller mycket lite text.
>
> **Nivå 2**
>
> I nivå 2 texterna längre. Men handlingen är enkel och väl disponerad, ord är >välkända, meningarna förhållandevis korta.
>
> **Nivå 3**
>
> Nivå 3 kräver ett större ordförråd. Här har språket har bisatser och och det >kan förekomma metaforer, meningarna är längre. Nivån är lämplig för läsare som >är på väg mot den "vanliga" litteraturen.

Personally I have only tried Level 3 which contains easier version of classics for example Anna Karenina. If you try the other levels you could comment and add your impressions.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please expand your answer a bit by adding what the three levels are and what the content of the books is? (E.g. do the books only contain texts? Footnotes? A glossary? Exercises even?)

Answer (score 0):

The German publisher Compact Verlag has a few "Lernkrimis" ("crime novels for [language] learning") in Swedish:

- One for level A1: [Mordet på fjorden](https://www.lernkrimi.de/lernkrimis-schwedisch/mordet-pa-fjorden-lernkrimi-kurzkrimis.html).
- Two for level A2: [Döden i Göteborg](https://www.lernkrimi.de/lernkrimis-schwedisch/doden-i-goteborg.html) and [Den blodiga stranden](https://www.lernkrimi.de/lernkrimis-schwedisch/den-blodiga-stranden-lernkrimi-horbuch.html) (the latter also has a CD with an audio-book version of the story).

These books contain vocabulary explanations on the same page as the text, a glossary, exercises to test text understanding and new vocabulary and notes on grammar.

The German publisher Harald Holder Verlag published [*Tösen från Stormyrtorpet / Das Mädchen vom Moorhof*](http://www.holder-augsburg-zweisprachig.de/schwedische-texte/lektuere-schwedisch-deutsch-tosen-fran-stormyrtorpet) by Selma Lagerlöf in a bilingual Swedish-German version. The description claims that Lagerlöf's simple language makes the book accessible to less advanced learners.